# Find eigenvalues of T : $P _2 ( R ) \to P _2 ( R )$ given by $( Tf )( t ) = tf ′ ( t ) + f (2) t + f (3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to figure out this homework problem. Can I get some help please?

Comment: You need to find $r\in R$ such that $T(f)=rf$ has a non-zero solution. Write $f$ in some basis; the powers of $t$ for example. $f(t)=at^2+bt+c$. Then the equation $T(f)=rf$ becomes $t(2at+b)+t(4a+2b+c)+(9a+3b+c)=r(at^2+bt+c)$. This is an equation between $t$-polynomials. Therefore the corresponding coefficients of the terms of the same degree must be equal. Equating them gives you a system of linear equations in which $a,b,c$ are the unknowns and $r$ is a parameter. You want the system to have a solution in which not all $a,b,c$ are zero. Therefore the determinant of the system must be $=0$

Comment: @SphericalTriangle That sounds like a good start for an answer. Why don't you post one?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I don't like endings, only starts. You can write a complete answer. That way you make sure you understood and get those online points.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle so I get the system of equations:
$\lambda$a=2a
$\lambda$b=4a+3b+c
$\lambda$c=9a+3b+c
what can I do with this?
I can only get $\lambda$=2 out of this. If I choose a=0, b and c would need to be 0 as well.

Comment: Organize the system $(2-\lambda)a=0, 4a+(3-\lambda)b+c=0, 9a+3b+(1-\lambda)c=0$. Equate the determinant of the matrix of the system to zero and that gives you the values of $\lambda$ that are eigenvalues. $\lambda=2$ is not one of those.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle Thank you! I got it!